# How to avoid the memory limit in R

Tags: r, memory

I'm trying to replace values in a matrix, specifically "t"->1 and "f"->0, but I keep getting the error messages:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.0 Mb
...    
Reached total allocation of 16345Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

I'm using a Win7 computer with 16GB of memory on the 64-bit version of R in RStudio.

what i'm currently running is

```
a <- matrix( dataset, nrow=nrow(dataset), ncol=ncol(dataset), byrow=TRUE)
memory.size()
a[a=="t"] <- 1
```

where dataset is a (about) 525000x300 size data frame. the `memory.size()` line gives me less than 4GB used, and `memory.limit()` is 16GB. Why is it that the replace line would require so much memory to execute? Is there any way to do the replace without hitting the memory limit (and are there any good tips on avoiding it in general), and if so, is it going to cost me a lot of time to run it? I'm still pretty new to R so I don't know if it makes a difference depending on the data class I use and how R allocates memory...

Comment: Is your Win7 OS 32bit or 64bit? R can use a lot of memory because it is, at its heart, functional, which means that functions shouldn't have side effects, which means that R frequently has to work on copies of data within functions.

Comment: You need to restart with minimal "competing" applications. 2MB is a fairly small memory request, and it is likely that you have a very fragmented memory map. Windows is unable to supply even a small contiguous block of memory, so time to save your needed data objects and code and then reboot.

Comment: I'm wondering if running `gc()` will help with the fragmented memory problem?

Comment: I'm running 64bit Win7. gc() didn't do much for making the replace line run. I will definitely try the reboot, but I don't see how that would fix the `Reached total allocation` problem?

Comment: If your entire matrix is made up of a few different characters, you could try using factors: `b<-as.factor(a);`; `rm(a)`; look at `levels(b)`; assign `levels(b)<-whatever`; `a <- matrix(b)`; `rm(b)`. I don't think we'll be able to tell you precisely why you're hitting that memory limit.

Comment: OT: If you want change t/f to 1/0 then `a <- as.integer(a=="t")` could be handy.

Comment: @Frank thanks for the advice on factors! my data is pretty mixed so I couldn't run it on the whole thing, but changing the levels for each column did the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

when you call this line

```
a[a=="t"] <- 1
```

R has to create a whole new boolean matrix to index into a.  If a is huge, this boolean matrix will also be huge.

Maybe you can try working on smaller sections of the matrix instead of trying to do it all in one shot.

```
for (i in 1:ncol(a)){
  ix = (a[:,i] == "t")
  a[ix,i] = 1
}
```

It's not fast or elegant, but it might get around the memory problem.

Comment: I can understand R creating a boolean matrix, but I don't understand how my allocated memory looks like it's all been allocated in the attempt when the original matrix was less than 2GB. Is maxing out the memory limit just a bad side effect from the original vector allocation attempt?